# How can I use a non-capturing group with Angular Router UI

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying to create a URL matching for a configuration page on my Angular site. I'm using [Angular Router UI](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) and according to [the documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) it should be possible to match non-capturing groups.

What I am trying to do is match both */config* and */configuration*. However I cannot get this to work, and when I click a link to ui-sref="configuration" I end up with an address which looks like this:
`localhost:8080/#/config( <--- Note the ending parenthesis`

Can anyone help me with this?

Code provided below.

```
// Define configuration module
angular.module('configuration')
    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('configuration', {
                url: '/config(?:uration)?',
                controller: 'ConfigurationController',
                templateUrl: 'visualization/configuration/configuration.html'
            });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give multiple urls to a single state in the above way. But, instead, you could use the $urlRouterProvider service to redirect a url to another. For help please read [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#urlrouterproviderwhenwhenpath-topath)

Comment: Would that work with extra parameters e.g. /config/<randomConfig> -> /configuration/<randomConfig>?

Comment: Yes you can do that with params

Comment: For the first part it seems to work. I do however have a problem with the parameters. Assume I want to allow /config/myconfig from any page, I'd use two parameters to fetch both start path and the configuration name. How would I go about to use the parameters in my toPath?

`$urlRouterProvider.when(/^{basePath:.*}\/config\/{loadConfig:.+$}/, 'basePath/configuration/loadConfig')`

Comment: Made this work. Examples with parameters was found in the samples in the Git repo.

`$urlRouterProvider
 .when('/config','/configuration')
 .when('/config/:loadConfig','/configuration/:loadConfig');
 .when('/:basePath/config/:loadConfig','/:basePath/configuration/:loadConfig');`

Comment: you can pass the param value directly in the toPath. Refer the doc here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters